What did Jesus eat immediately after his fasting in the desert?
We read in Lk 4:1:4 ( KJV):

And Jesus being full of the Holy Ghost returned from Jordan, and was led by the Spirit into the wilderness, Being forty days tempted of the devil. And in those days he did eat nothing: and when they were ended, he afterward hungered. And the devil said unto him, If thou be the Son of God, command this stone that it be made bread.And Jesus answered him, saying, It is written, That man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word of God

Note the clause ' shall not live by bread alone ' . Jesus does not rule out the importance of physical bread in sustaining a person's  life . And Verse 2 says that he hungered. But for the devil's appearance, Jesus would have eaten something say, some wild berries. But he gives a befitting reply to Satan, which implies that he did not eat in front of the devil.
Now, the Gospels record three temptations without mentioning the period of intervention between first, second and third. After the second one Jesus orders Satan  to get behind him, implying that there was definitely  a break between the second and third temptations. Verse 13  goes on to state that having completed all the temptations,  the devil left Jesus 'for a season' , implying again that the three temptations did not take place in one go, and that  Jesus definitely ate something during the interim, because he was hungry. My question is : What did Jesus eat immediately after his fasting in the desert ? Was he given food as had Prophet Elijah been by  ravens ( 1 Kings 17:2-6) ? Are there any apocryphal writings available on the subject.

Short Answer: The Gospels do not mention what Jesus ate.
I can't speak for all the apocryphal writings. However, the canonical Gospels don't mention what Jesus ate. To be frank, the focus was likely on how Jesus responded rather than what he ate.
At least to me, it would be quite odd to quote Deuteronomy 8:3 - man shall not live on bread alone, but man shall live on everything that comes out of the mouth of the Lord, and then start talking about what Jesus ate. The focus was on the spiritual lesson. Jesus’ triumph over temptation. His "living" on the word of God.
Just a small note:
Matthew 4:11 NASB says:

Then the devil *left Him; and behold, angels came and began to serve
Him.

Could this imply that angels might have provided Jesus with food similar to how Elijah was given food by an angel in 1 Kings 19:5-8? Maybe.

Here's what we know from the text:

Jesus fasted for forty days and nights before the temptations began (Matthew 4:2, Luke 4:2)

Obviously during this period, he did not eat anything.

The exact duration is not specified.

Reading through both Matthew 4:2-11 and Luke 4:2-13, the temptations appear to be described in a way that suggests they occurred in quick succession.
Given that Jesus had been fasting for forty days, I think that it is reasonable to assume that he remained hungry throughout the temptations. However, since the text is silent on the matter I think it best I do not overstep and say anything further than the text itself and focus on the spiritual lessons.

Thanks, Jason_. I too thought of Mtt 4:11. Angels came after all the temptations ended. My question is : was Jesus hungry through the period of the temptations which may have taken a few days to complete.

Your short answer implies that the correct response would have been to Vote to Close as 'opinion based'. Please don't answer questions unless they are clearly in line with the site scope.

@Stevecanhelp Thank you for your feedback. I had considered it. He asked about apocryphal writings which mainly stayed my hand as I am not versed enough to make a decision based on those. I haven't quite mastered when to vote "opinion based". To me, the right answer is simply "we don't know", although, I can see why it might attract opinion-based answers. I’ll try to be more mindful of this in the future.

Sure, thanks! No worries, it's great to see you've spent a lot of time in the Close Votes queue, that's the way to practice that. We've had a few users not VTC'ing obviously off topic questions the past few months, so we're just trying to be a bit more active in encouraging others to hit the button :)

Thanks, Steve can help, for voting to close the question in as much as it helps me in asking more sensible question. But, as per your Profile, BHE is a democratic forum that encourages diversity of views ! The Gospels do mention what the Baptist ate, and what Jesus was searching for on the fig tree on his way. After all, I am looking for extra-Biblical references ;  call them apocrypha or otherwise ! Ancient traditions like that of Ethiopia are known to have precious sources of information relating to early Christianity. Let us be open to their perspectives.

We are not told what Jesus ate to break His 40 day fast.  Therefore we do not know.
However, there MIGHT be a hint.  In Ps 78 is a song rehearing the goodness of God, especially God protection and provision for Israel during their 40 year wandering in the desert.  Now let us note two facts:

Num 14:34 - In keeping with the forty days you spied out the land, you shall bear your guilt forty years—a year for each day—and you will experience My alienation.

Thus, it appears that Jesus spent 40 days in the desert just as Israel spent 40 years in the desert.  Next we note that manna is described as follows:

Ps 78:24, 25 - He rained down manna for them to eat; He gave them grain from heaven. Man ate the bread of angels; He sent them food in abundance.

Lastly, at the end of Jesus' 40 days in the desert we are told:

Matt 4:11 - Then the devil left Him, and angels came and ministered to Him.

Therefore, it MIGHT be possible that Jesus was given manna to eat.  Having said that, we are not specifically told so we do not know for sure.

As you say, we can't know, but that's an interesting and surprisingly plausible connection I'd never thought of making.

Thanks, Dottard. Jesus hungered implies that he was short of physical energy. He could not have, as fully human, climb the high mountain ( Lk 4:5) and Temples Pinnacle ( Lk 4:9) with an empty stomach. Angels came in only after Satan had left . Mind that Jesus was not very particular of eating from the table, as is evident from the event around the fig tree. It was not the season of ripe figs and Jesus was looking for tender figs , not that pleasing to the tongue.
